# Classic Landing Pages and CloudPages Inventory - Using API to retrieve details for what was created

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page

It's 2020 and many have already started transitioning their legacy ExactTarget landing pages from Classic Tools (which is going to likely sunset in 2020) to the newer Cloud Pages. Is there any automated way to extract all the name, url and folder location of the classic landing pages using SOAP API or any other process? I know the list [supported operations for SOAP objects and methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm) does not list Landing Pages as retrievable but I just want to check if there is something undocumented that I'm unaware of.

Also, is it possible to do the same for CloudPages perhaps with SOAP or REST since they are newer? I ask because it will be very useful.

At this point for either Landing Pages or CloudPages I've just put a lot of the pages details in an excel spreadsheet but it is very manual/tedious and it would be nice to do this using an automated way for quick inventory purposes. For those with hundreds of these it seems like this would feature is long overdue such as what is active and what is paused as well as attributes such as it's folder location, pageurl, creation date and last modified date.

Comment: Landing pages and Microsites have no current EOL, the current EOL just deals with creating/editing emails in email studio

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as it currently stands there is no public REST endpoint nor SOAP object to interact with Landingpages or Cloudpages.  All of this is handled via internal API endpoints inside of the UI and all exploration on the undocumented endpoints did not turn up anything related to this.

I am hopeful as they roll out the new dynamic content integrations (from the Rebel acquisition) that we are able to get more public facing REST endpoints and that these will include Cloudpages - but there has been nothing official about this.

There are some things you can pull via the developer tools (network tab) from the Internal APIs when on the UI to help, but nothing that is truly independent of being logged into the platform.